# QT Creator: Trigger a Slot with Code?

Tags: qt, combobox, action, slots

I may have worked myself into a corner but this sounded to me like a good idea at the time.

I have been developing an interface that permits a user to modify settings of a robotic device, i.e. speed, directions, force, etc.  with a very large series of options in the form of ComboBoxes.  The problem is that there are about a thousand of these things, in sub categories.  e.g. Speed category x1, x2, x3, Y1, y2, etc.  So rather than create a thousand comboboxes in QT, I thought the good idea was to create one set of 50 (ish) and then provide a few button to switch between categories.  So when the user selects speed QT, populates the comboboxes with the appropriate options, sets the style sheets and text for the labels etc.  So it appears as though a dedicated page exists.  Then if the user selects Direction, QT Writes the current index of each box to a dedicated array and then repopulates the boxes, labels etc with the appropriate content.  I then do this over and over for the various needs of the system.

All of that seems to work fine.  However I am now in a bind where the options provided to navigate to each page have grown.  For instance I have forward / backward buttons (like you woudl expect in a set-up wizard), as well as action menus at the top to jump to a page.  So now the code is becoming very repetitious. If you select the next button, I write the current values to array, then repopulate.  If you jump to the page from anywhere, I look to see where I am, write it to array, and populate the boxes.  Thus if I need to change anything I have to make the change in numerous places in the code.

I know that this is not optimal.  What I woudl like to do is run a continuous loop as I woudl normally do with Micros in C.  So the program can look at a variable in each pass and if it is then it does. I am not however skilled enough to figure this loop out in QT.  So my new thought was...

Is it possible to trigger an action or slot with a variable.  For example, if the user presses the Next button it triggers a slot for a button that does not exist, so that QT will execute a particular line of Code? Then I can have 1 dedicated section focused on reading and writing boxes, with a bunch of actions that will take me there.

Comment: It's not clear why FWD/BCK button has to use a different code for combos than direct nav. In both case it's "'save current screen, fill new screen" ...?

Comment: :) I do appreciate your feedback.  You are probably correct, I am just a naive Mech. Engineer trying to figure it out.  I will look into this though.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a signal that is triggered with an `emit` call in your code, so you'd hook up the next button signal of clicked to a slot that does some work and moves on, or directly calls another signal that you've created that triggers a slot elsewhere, or do some work in a lambda triggered by the button press.

Comment: I like it, Thanks  I am not real familiar with this, but I will play around.  Best regards.

Comment: for example? `emit qaction->trigger();`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160476/using-emit-vs-calling-a-signal-as-if-its-a-regular-function-in-qt

Answer (score 0):

I would first load all the ComboBoxes options in a QStringList array (or maybe an array of `QList<QLatin1String>` lists - for memory saving and code efficiency).

Then I would keep an array of a 1000 integers for current ComboBox indexes.

When the user changes a value in some ComboBox, the currentIndexChanged signal will trigger the corresponding slot (a single slot for all the ComboBoxes would be enough - `sender()->objectName()` to get the name of the ComboBox which had sent the signal):

```
void WindowWidget::on_ComboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index) 
{ 
    name = sender()->objectName();
    /* here change the corresponding integer in the current
       indexes array */
}
```

On Next/Back button push repopulate the ComboBoxes. Also, provide some 'Save' button for saving the ComboBoxes indexes (or trigger the Save slot on some action, i.e. on window close either even on a timer signal).