# hide QWidget from a different QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a MainWindow with two widgets, buttonsWidget and infoWidget. 
I'm trying to to hide infoWidget after clicking a button within buttonsWidget (and ultimately show a different widget).

I've tried:

mainwindow.h

```
public:
void hideInfo();
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::hideInfo()
{
ui->info->hide();
}
```

buttonsWidget.cpp

```
void buttonsWidget::on_timingButton_clicked()
{
MainWindow::hideInfo();

//Then will do something to show 'timingWidget'..

}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) for this.

Add a signal in the buttonsWidget.h.

```
signals:
    void hideInfoSignal();
```

In the main function, connect the button signal with the mainwindow method hideInfo().

```
QObject::connect(this->info, SIGNAL(hideInfoSignal),this, SLOT(hideInfo));
```

I haven't tested this, because I dont have Qt on this machine, but that should work, with possible minor modifications. If any errors appear, let me know and I will help. Also, read the signals and slots documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the end I did:

*buttonsWidget.h*
signals:
void hideInfoSignal();

*infowidget.h*
public slots:
void hideInfo();

*buttonsWidget.cpp*
on_timing_button_clicked(){
hideInfoSignal();
}

*infoWidget.cpp*
hideInfo(){
this->hide;
}

*mainWindow.cpp*
connect(ui->buttons, SIGNAL(hideinfoSignal), ui->info, SLOT(hideInfo))

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: That looks fine! But just so you know, the documentation says to emit a signal you should put the keyword "emit" before calling the signal. Like this: "emit hideInfoSignal()". The diffrence between using emit vs calling a signal was discussed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160476/using-emit-vs-calling-a-signal-as-if-its-a-regular-function-in-qt

Comment: sorry to trouble you again - I'm trying to now show a different widget in it's place.
I have :   connect(ui->buttons, SIGNAL(showTimingSignal()), ****, Slot (showTImingScreen()));

What do I have where there is the ****?

Comment: Should be a reference to the object in which the slot showTImingScreen() is defined.