# QObject::connect: signal not found

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a `MainWindow` class which is declared in `mainwindow.h` and defined in `mainwindow.cpp` respectively like this:

In mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ...
    void addNewTab(QString fullFilePath, QString textString="");

public slots:
    void disableMenuItem();
    ...

private:
    ...
};
```

In mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ...
    connect(this, &MainWindow::addNewTab, this, &MainWindow::disableMenuItem); 
    ...
}

void MainWindow::addNewTab(QString fullFilePath, QString textString)
{
    ...
}

void MainWindow::disableMenuItem()
{
   ...
}
```

Everything compiles and run fine except for the following message on the console:

```
QObject::connect: signal not found in MainWindow
```

The message come from the `connect` call in the constructor above. What does that message mean in my case, and where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you forget the `Q_OBJECT` macro?

Comment: @LogicStuff: No, see edit.

Comment: Is `addNewTab()` in the signals section of your header?

Comment: @drescherjm: No, see added code above.

Comment: Then I would say that is the problem. And Qt is telling you.

Comment: You forget to declare 'signal' before declaring signal function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422154/my-slot-is-not-invoked-called-used-working-executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As drescherjm and Learner mentioned, you forgot to add a `signals:` section to your header file, and declare your signal within it.

Qt connects signals to slots at runtime, not at compile time, so mis-connected signals and slots cannot be detected until the program is actually run; that's why this problem is reported when it is.

Qt uses the *moc* preprocessor to turn `signals` and `slots` into standard c++, so that's why the `signals:` and `slots:` sections of your header will not cause problems when compiling.

Signals are fully defined by moc, so you do not need to define them in your .cpp file, but they still need to be in the header so moc knows to create them.

**EDIT:**
It appears that you are trying to use a signal with the name of one of your class functions. I don't think that's going to work. [the documentation for the new signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) indicates that you can connect *TO* anything, it doesn't have to be a slot, but I believe you still need to define your signal *as* a signal.

Comment: I tried to declare "signals:" above the addNewTab() function and got the following error message during compilation: multiple definition of `MainWindow::addNewTab(QString, QString)'

Comment: @Amani see my edit: you'll need to use a signal name that does not clash with an already defined function name. The signal name has to be unique - think of it like a totally separate function, one that is called by `emit functionName()`, and ends up calling whatever you've connected to it.

Comment: also note that [the emit is not necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160476/using-emit-vs-calling-a-signal-as-if-its-a-regular-function-in-qt), but I would encourage its use for clarity.

Comment: @Amani since you say "everything runs fine", I suspect that you don't really need to use connect, or signals/slots at all in this instance. It sounds like, inside your *addNewTab* function, you are directly calling *disableMenuItem*. If that's true, you do not need to have the `connect` line at all, nor the signal, nor define *disableMenuItem* as a slot.

Comment: If you wish to use signals/slots, you would instead call `emit functionName()` after you have connected *functionName* to *disableMenuItem*. I find this most useful within a single class if I only want the receiving slot to be called in certain situations, and then I can connect and disconnect the signal from the slot as needed.