# What are 'user keywords' in the codeblocks IDE?

Tags: c++, c, ide, codeblocks

I've just noticed something interesting in the `codeblocks` IDE, via the **editor settings > syntax highlighting**, Saying 'User keywords', I am aware that they are reserved keywords such as for, int, signed, etc but what are these supposed to be?

My best guess is that it really means 'symbolic constants'. Google and Stack overflow doesn't seem to give me any information on what they are. However I do know that you can't really create your own keywords because they are part of the `C/C++` language.

Any ideas? just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I do know that you can't really create your own keywords because they are part of the C/C++ language

You can't create your own in such a way that a compiler will understand. You need to separate what your IDE does from what your compiler does. The IDE has a facility for displaying keywords with a special color. That's easy to understand. But CodeBlocks doesn't rely on the compiler you use to "figure out" a token is a keyword. It has its own processor for this.

So what happens when you update your compiler and it supports a newer version of the language? Your IDE can't magically follow suit. It won't support those new keywords out of the box. That's why it allows you to specify "user keywords". So you may see the new keywords highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, you can not create new keywords in C++. As you noticed this option is for syntax highlighting. You can enter there any words if you want to highlight them in the code editor. The code editor will highlight your words to make it easier to identify them in the code. Highlighting or in other words colorizing is the only purpose of that settings.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a user keyword might be `emit` when invoking a Qt signal. Although qt signals are technically functions, they are meta compiled and are designed to mutate state outside their class scope. That's why many developers like to explicitly decorate them.

Typically `emit` <strike>evaluates</strike> macro expands to nothing

See this question for an explanation on how emit works:

[Using emit vs calling a signal as if it's a regular function in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160476/using-emit-vs-calling-a-signal-as-if-its-a-regular-function-in-qt)

Often compilers will have their own keywords that aren't officially in the standard. For example, GCC (C++) supports numerous C11 keywords like `__thread` or `__restrict`. You might need to manually add these to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: I would rather say that `emit` is macro-expanded (not "evaluated") to nothing