# Static Assert Signal or Slot

Tags: c++, qt, static-analysis

Is there a way to `Q_STATIC_ASSERT` that a function is a `Q_SLOT` or `Q_SIGNAL`?

This would be used to avoid mistakes using `std::invoke`

```
Q_STATIC_ASSERT(func is Q_SIGNAL?)
Q_EMIT std::invoke(func, ...);
```

Comment: Try to find the text `Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QtPrivate::HasQ_OBJECT_Macro ...` in the Qt source file `\Src\qtbase\src\corelib\kernel\qobject.h`. May be that idea will help you find or write what you need.

Comment: Also not that you can simply emit signal without `emit` or `Q_EMIT` keywords, just like common method call - `func();` or `object->func();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10160476/4149835

Comment: I suppose I'll dig around the private API some more to see if there are hidden gems I missed on a first pass. I was just hoping that there would be an easy way to leverage MOC to detect misuse of accidentally "emitting" a non-signal function.

Comment: I still do not get what the goal of this exercise is. If it is indeed _to detect misuse of accidentally "emitting" a non-signal function._, how can one misuse something, which is controlled solely by the framework? You might try to write `emit` all over your code and nothing would change in the code's behavior. You might as well decide to remove it completely - nothing would change either. If you want to keep the code readable, write instead linter rules for ensuring a signal call is preceded by the `emit` keyword and leave `assert` alone.